# Biopython, import error with "import Bio"

Tags: anaconda, biopython

I have installed `Biopython` by `Anaconda` on Windows.

When I try `import Bio` I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'`

Why?

Comment: How did you install biopython? Is it case sensitive (should it be `import bio`)?

Comment: @darthbith I have installed Biopython by `conda install -c conda-forge biopython `, and I already have tried both `Bio` and `bio`.

Comment: Did you install it into a new environment, or into the root environment? Essentially, you have not provided enough details here for anyone to be able to help. Could you please list all of the steps that you took, including the commands where relevant?

Comment: @darthbith I have created a new environment, in which I have installed only Biopython.

Comment: And did you activate that environment before you ran python? Please put all your steps into the question...

Comment: @darthbith I have activated the environment than I have run:

 `import numpy as np`,

`import pandas as pd `,
 
`import Bio`.

Comment: *Please include all of the details in the post as I have requested.* You need to include all of the exact steps you used to create the environment and how you started Python, then your imports. I cannot help further until you do so. Your information is not consistent. You state "I have created a new environment, in which I have installed only Biopython" then you try to import Pandas, which is not a dependency of Biopython according to the recipe at https://github.com/conda-forge/biopython-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Comment: Try this `from Bio import Phylo`

Comment: @A.Raza The issue is that when I try to access to *Bio* by `import Bio` I get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simone.. it looks like your installation did go wrong somehow. Regardless of why and how try the following stepwise approach to see if your import error remains.

On Windows (the dots denote your installed program path specifics):

> e.g. go to: C:\....\Anaconda...\Lib\site-packages

find and remove folders using `delete`.

> folder 1: "\Bio"
>
> folder 2: "\biopython-1.70.dist-info"

The version value 1.70 might be 1.69 when using `conda` for installation.

> **Empty your trashbin.** This way the system can't do tricks and recover or link to deleted files and folders.

Install `pip` if its not and grab it from [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

> try **`pip install biopython --no-cache-dir`**

Voila! Hope it works now for you too... Enjoy!

In case its not check windows environment variables\path.. via control panel>advanced system settings to include PATH to site-packages. Or do similar on other OS.

Comment: I have followed your procedure, unfortunately when I try `pip install bio --no-cache-dir` or `pip install bio` I get this message `Collecting bio could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bio (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for bio`

Comment: my bad... it should be `biopython`. I'll correct it in the answer too. That was a typo from my side. I normally have `import biopython as bio`. So used to it ;-)

Comment: ..normally when I install a new biopython version I will store the old one as  "bioptyhon_versionXYZ"  and the new one as current version for compatibility reasons; if issues appear along the road I refer in the code to the older version inline. That saves a lot of debugging and when compiled ....who sees it anyway this "quick-go-around-a-possible-bug-or-renaming-issue"?